# How to know if a particular ethereum address is receiving a transaction?

Tags: addresses, pending-transactions, payments

Is it possible to determine if an ethereum address is receving a payment for example?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way would be to search the adress on etherscan: 
https://etherscan.io/address/"address_you_want"

Comment: Yes, sure but in this way i don't know for example if I'm receiving a transaction.
For example if I have a wallet, and somebody is sending me a certain amount of ether,  could I detect this? or I have to poll getBalance every x seconds?